# What does this syntax mean: const foo = () => {}

Tags: javascript

I have recently come across this code with which I am unfamiliar:

```
const foo = () => {
    /*code block here*/
}
```

As far as I can tell, it means the same thing as:

```
const foo = function () {
    /*code block here*/
}
```

Is that a correct assumption, or are there differences? 
What is the correct name to refer to this bit of code?
What exactly is the '=>' doing? I've never seen it in Javascript before.

Comment: `arrow function`

Comment: it's part of es6 syntax, find more on google - (fat) arrow function

Comment: its a Arrow function see this [mdn document](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjvxPn63sHTAhXLqY8KHSk5BGIQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions%2FArrow_functions&usg=AFQjCNEJ7j1iiQ3p-iy7u9L78rzUyEGUHg)

Comment: did you try to google it ?

Comment: @Vovan—did you try googling "foo = () => {}"? ;-)

Comment: @RobG yes i did. Try to google 'javascript  () => {}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ES6 arrow function. It's basically same as `function (){}`,
 with some differences such as not rebinding `this`.

[Reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Description)

Comment: All execution contexts have a *this*. Arrow functions adopt the *this* of their enclosing (or "outer") execution context.

Comment: @RobG the description is basically based on MDN section title, "No binding of this".

Comment: MDN is not an authority, it's just a (very helpful) public wiki.

Comment: @RobG I have altered the word to "rebind" so it may be clearer.

Comment: [*ECMA-262 ed 7 §14.2.16*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation) says "*An ArrowFunction does not define **local** bindings for arguments, super, this, or new.target. Any reference to arguments, super, this, or new.target within an ArrowFunction must resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing environment.*" (my emphasis). So guess whether there is a local binding or not is moot, it just must evaluate to the outer value. Saying "no binding" makes it sound like there isn't one at all (IMHO of course). ;-)